# Problem with memory limit exceeded

Tags: google-earth-engine, memoryerror

I have problems in GEE with the usage of memory. I am trying to run a script and every time I try to make any operation with my image collections it runs out of memory (`"User memory limit exceeded"`). I seek any help that doesn´t include reducing my time period of images because I need my composed variables with the images like this. Here is the script and link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3822ad4de9cb2f42cf66ca1ea0fafa48

```
//Dates of study
var date_start2019 = ee.Date('2019-01-01');
var date_end2019= ee.Date('2019-12-31');

//Filtrado de imagenes por diferentes parámetros
var imagenT1_2019 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') 
              .select(['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B9', 'B11', 'B12', 'SCL'])
              .filterBounds(geometryT1)
              .filterDate(date_start2019.advance(-30,'day'), date_end2019.advance(30,'day'))
              .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than',70)
              .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'EQUALS','30TWK')
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER', SON94))
              ////.map(masked)
               //.map(function(image){return image.clip(SEjucar)})

//print (imagenT1_2019, 'Imagen_filtrada_2019');
//Map.addLayer(imagenA, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'ImagenA');

//Obtener imagenes como una lista de imagenes
var imgListT1_2019 = imagenT1_2019.toList (999)
//print ('ListOfImages_T1_2019',imgListT1_2019)

//#############################################################################################//
//Temporal Gap-Filling with Linear Interpolation (relleno de imagenes con anterior y posterior)

//Add a band containing timestamp to each image.
imagenT1_2019 = imagenT1_2019.map(function(image) {
  var timeImage = image.metadata('system:time_start').rename('timestamp')
  var timeImageMasked = timeImage.updateMask(image.mask().select(0))
  return image.addBands(timeImageMasked)
})

//Next we specify the time-window
var days = 100
var millis = ee.Number(days).multiply(1000*60*60*24)

//Join 1: Join the collection with itself to find all images after 
//each image that are winthin the time-window.
var maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: millis,
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

var lessEqFilter = ee.Filter.lessThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

var filter1 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, lessEqFilter)
 
var join1 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'after',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: false})
   
var join1ResultT1_2019 = join1.apply({
  primary: imagenT1_2019,
  secondary: imagenT1_2019,
  condition: filter1
})

//Join 2: Join the collection with itself to match all images
//within the time-window that come before each image.
var greaterEqFilter = ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

var filter2 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, greaterEqFilter)
 
var join2 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'before',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: true})
   
var join2ResultT1_2019 = join2.apply({
  primary: join1ResultT1_2019,
  secondary: join1ResultT1_2019,
  condition: filter2
})
//The collection is now ready for interpolation. We write a function 
//that will be used to interpolate all images.
var interpolateImages = function(image) {
  image = ee.Image(image)
  // We get the list of before and after images from the image property
  // Mosaic the images so we a before and after image with the closest unmasked pixel
  var beforeImages = ee.List(image.get('before'))
  var beforeMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(beforeImages).mosaic()
  var afterImages = ee.List(image.get('after'))
  var afterMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(afterImages).mosaic()
  // Get image with before and after times
  var t1 = beforeMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t1')
  var t2 = afterMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t2')
  var t = image.metadata('system:time_start').rename('t')
  var timeImage = ee.Image.cat([t1, t2, t])
  var timeRatio = timeImage.expression('(t - t1) / (t2 - t1)', {
    't': timeImage.select('t'),
    't1': timeImage.select('t1'),
    't2': timeImage.select('t2'),
  })
  // Compute an image with the interpolated image y
  var interpolated = beforeMosaic
    .add((afterMosaic.subtract(beforeMosaic).multiply(timeRatio)))
  // Replace the masked pixels in the current image with the average value
  var result = image.unmask(interpolated)
  return result.copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
}

var interpolatedColT1_2019 = ee.ImageCollection(join2ResultT1_2019.map(interpolateImages));
//print (interpolatedColT1_2019,'interpolatedCol_T1_2019')
var imgInterpolT1_2019 = interpolatedColT1_2019.toList(999)


//#############################################################################################//
//Temporal Gap-Filling with Linear Interpolation (relleno de imagenes con anterior y posterior)

//Part 1 — Sentinel-2 time-series acquisition and pre-processing (Hecho arriba)

//Part 2 — Creation of monthly composites 

//create list of period-image from 1 to 24 in a year
var n = 15;
var endDate2019 = date_start2019.advance(360, 'days') //Todo esto hay q hacerlo para los 4 años y luego unirlos
var totalDays2019 = endDate2019.difference(date_start2019, 'day');
var daysToInterpolate2019 = ee.List.sequence(1, totalDays2019, n)
//separate by years
var years = ee.List.sequence(date_start2019.get("year"),
                             date_end2019.get("year"));
//compute median value per month
var composite = years.map(function (y) {
     return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(daysToInterpolate2019.map(function (d) {
       var a = ee.Algorithms.If (ee.Number(d).lt(22),ee.Number(0),ee.Number(21))
      return interpolatedColT1_2019.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(ee.Number(y).subtract(ee.Number(1)), y, 'year'))
                       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(ee.Number(d).subtract(ee.Number(a)),ee.Number(d).add(ee.Number(21)),'DAY_OF_YEAR'))
                       .median()
                       .set('DAY_OF_YEAR',d, 'year',y);
    }))
  });

//PART 2.2
//decompose list of img collection into list of images
function decomposeList(l) {
  return ee.ImageCollection(l).toList(24)
}
var list_imgsT1_2019 = composite.map(decomposeList).flatten();
//set system id and system index according to year and month
function renameImages(img1) {
  var img = ee.Image(img1);
  var value = ee.Number(img.get('year')).format('%04d')
          .cat('_').cat(ee.Number(img.get('DAY_OF_YEAR')).format('%03d'));
  return ee.Image(img.set('system:index', value, 'system:id',value))
}
var list_imgs_renamedT1_2019 = list_imgsT1_2019.map(renameImages);
//convert from list to img collection
var decomposed_collectionT1_2019 = ee.ImageCollection(list_imgs_renamedT1_2019);

print (decomposed_collectionT1_2019, 'decomposed_collection_T1_2019')
var imgList2T1_2019 = decomposed_collectionT1_2019.toList (999)
```

Comment: can you share your asset 'projects/ee-dcerezorebe/assets/SE_Jucar_ETRS89'?

Comment: This is a `1200+` line script, so I won't delve into the details. I assume the problem is that you turn all your image collections into lists, which tend to cause memory problems. Try to rewrite this using collections only. There's a lot of duplication in this script, try to extract that into functions.

Comment: [compose-a-question](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help#compose-a-question), [avoid-converting-to-list-unnecessarily](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#avoid-converting-to-list-unnecessarily), [join-vs.-map-filter](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#join-vs.-map-filter), [use the profiler to find high memory operations](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/playground#profiler)